# Plot with las=2 cutting off varnames

Tags: r, plot

I have long varnames and, to display them all in a plot, I've generated (in R) a graph that rotates them 90 degrees:

```
> plot(df$varname, las=2)
```

However, the graph cuts off the first half of the longest varnames.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce the axis label size + rotate them to the side (with ggplot2)

```
library(ggplot2)

df<- data.frame(varname=c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"),value=c(1,2))

ggplot(df, aes(varname,value))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        text = element_text(size=10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Increase the size of the bottom margin:

```
op <- par(mar = c(8,4,4,2) + 0.1) ## default is c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
plot(df$varname, las = 2)
par(op) ## reset plot margins to default
```

Iterate until your labels fit in.